# signpass error: Couldn't find an identity for pass.com.xxx.xxxx (continued)

Tags: xcode, passkit

I have used the pass kit demos provided by Apple and made some changes, bought a new MacBook and the error "Couldn't find an identity for pass for pass.com.xxx.xxx" has came up. I did admittedly make a silly mistake of not downloading the certificates again thinking iCloud would do that for me. However, even after doing that and double checking it in the keychain, it still comes up with the same error. I have checked the passTypeIdentifier and the teamIdentifier.

[signpass error:Couldn't find an identity for pass.com.xxx.xxxx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13045639/signpass-errorcouldnt-find-an-identity-for-pass-com-xxx-xxxx)

I turned to jsonlint to ensure that my pass.json file was free from errors. The file was validated so I am left a bit clueless as to what the problem may be.

[Passbook: Couldn't find a passTypeIdentifier in the pass?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26457097/passbook-couldnt-find-a-passtypeidentifier-in-the-pass)

When I execute: ./signapss -p /myPass in terminal, it shows:

```
2016-12-25 13:15:19.219 signpass[4024:556398] {
    "icon.png" = ba47a8021c8d74d2146d7244c8a0566be37df43b;
    "icon@2x.png" = bd5442b4b08aa4dde333ec9ef0269e7fd93140b3;
    "logo.png" = 6d4e7410569679d1ad9ec8040b072d5c6fc46285;
    "logo@2x.png" = a718ffd4e611e404dd3eb701454bcaefdabbe311;
    "pass.json" = bf3b10c7b714fccd38e564e30d2b9342a016615c;
}
2016-12-25 13:15:19.236 signpass[4024:556398] Couldn't find an identity for pass.com.VirtualCard.Virtual-Card
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When moving from a old Mac device to another there is a key that also needs to be transferred and apple's security needs to be contacted. Upon contacting them they refer you to this https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/Troubleshooting/Troubleshooting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH5-SW1 to import. You can either go down that route or just generate another certificate from scratch and use that instead which is what I have done.